# Django + TelegramClient RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, telegram

I'm trying to make a parser like a web application. Where, from the POST form, the username of the telegram group will be sent with a request, parsing the data of users of this group and saving to a file. I transferred this parser to Celery, in view I call this function and I give the name of the group as a parameter and request. I get this error RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.

If run without Django, the code works fine

My tasks.py

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import csv
from celery import shared_task


@shared_task
def main(url):
    
    api_id = ********
    api_hash = '********'
    phone = '******'
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
    
    client.connect()
    
    target_group = client.get_entity(url)
    
    print('Fetching Members...')
    all_participants = []
    all_participants = client.get_participants(target_group, aggressive=True)
    
    print('Saving In file...')
    with open("members.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
        writer.writerow(['username','user id', 'access hash','name','group', 'group id'])
        for user in all_participants:
            if user.username:
                username= user.username
            else:
                username= ""
            if user.first_name:
                first_name= user.first_name
            else:
                first_name= ""
            if user.last_name:
                last_name= user.last_name
            else:
                last_name= ""
            name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
            writer.writerow([username ,user.id, user.access_hash, name, target_group.title, target_group.id])      
    print('Members scraped successfully.')
```

My view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .tasks import main


@csrf_exempt
def join_the_group(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.POST['group-name']
        main(url)
        return render(request, 'ParseUserData/main_form.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'ParseUserData/main_form.html')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/ParserJSON/ParseUserData/views.py", line 10, in join_the_group
    main()
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 182, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 411, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/ParserJSON/ParseUserData/tasks.py", line 12, in main
    client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 335, in __init__
    if not callable(getattr(self.loop, 'sock_connect', None)):
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 483, in loop
    return helpers.get_running_loop()
  File "/home/dev/Desktop/DjangoParser/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 433, in get_running_loop
    return asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 639, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
[20/Aug/2023 01:32:00] "POST /user-data/collection-name HTTP/1.1" 500 104535
```

Comment: Also, please paste the trace as a code block. Your app seems to have an option at the top for the cut-and-paste view, use that and paste it into a code block for maximum legibility here.

Comment: @joanis The code is pasted as a block of code. Everything looks right to me, as it should. Try refreshing the page or something like that. I think it's your problem

Comment: Your code blocks are good, agreed. What I'm asking for is the full error trace to be also added as text, in a code block, rather than as a screen capture.

Comment: Thank you, much better! Now hopefully someone here knows how to solve your problem.